# How to keep $_get['id']

Tags: php, html, sql

So I am trying to create a school portal, and right now i am trying to find a way to add students to my existing classes. I can successfully add classes, and view them, but when I try to add students to them, it all goes wrong. This is the page that shows my existing classes in a table, and on the right I have the option to add students to that class. It takes the class ID, and adds it to the url of the next page(addtoclass.php)

```
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("connection.php");

//fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM class INNER JOIN yeargroup ON class.yeargroup_id=yeargroup.id INNER JOIN section ON class.section_id=section.id INNER JOIN subject ON class.subject_id=subject.ID INNER JOIN teacher ON class.teacher_id=teacher.ID ORDER BY yeargroup_id ASC, section_id ASC"); // using mysqli_query instead

?>

<html>
<head>    
    <title>View class</title>
</head>

<body>

    <table width='80%' border=0>
        <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Class Name</td>
            <td>Teacher </td>
            <td>Yeargroup</td>
            <td>Subject</td>
            <td>Section</td>
            <td>Manage </td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$res['class_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$res['classname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$res['surname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$res['yeargroup_description']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$res['subject_description']."</td>";   
            echo "<td>".$res['section_description']."</td>";  
            echo "<td><a href=\"addtoclass.php?id=$res[class_id]\">Add students</a> | <a href=\"viewstudentsfromclass.php?id=$res[class_id]\">View current students</a></td>";                     
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

So now, in the next page, I use `$id=$_GET['id']` to retrieve the ID from the URL, and ideally I would then add the students the admins select from the dropdown menu into the class with the ID from the url.

```
include "connection.php";
        $id= $_GET['id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student";
        $result= mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    //    $query1 = "SELECT id FROM class WHERE id='$id'";
     //   $result1= mysqli_query($conn,$query1);
      //  echo $result1;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SSWL Portal</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="addtoclass.php" method="POST">
            <div>
                <label>Student</label>
        <select name="student">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled"> Select one from below...</option>
            <?php 
            while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rows['ID']?>"><?php echo $rows['name'].$rows['surname']?></option>
            <?php
            }?>
        </select> <br>
                <button type="sumbit" name="btnAddstudent" class="float" value ="btnAddstudent">Add New Student</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <a href="../logout.php">Logout</a>
    </body>


    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["btnAddstudent"])) {

        $student= $_POST["student"];

$query2= "INSERT INTO student_class (student_ID,class_ID) VALUES '($student','$id')";
if  (!mysqli_query($conn,$query2))
{
    echo "error";
}
else
{
    echo "success";
}

    }
    ?>
```

When I select the students from the dropdown menu and press the 'Add new student' button, I get the error

> "Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\sswl\admin\addtoclass.php on line 4".

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do, or to keep the `$id` from the url from before I press the button?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
I will also link a picture of my database below.

[image]

Comment: you'll just need to check whether the get variable is present before anything else since its the starting point for everything that you need to do in the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `id` in to your form action like this:

```
...
<form action="addtoclass.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="POST">

...
```

> Your code is vulnerable for SQL injections. I advice you to use
>   prepared statements in case when you need to perform an SQL queries.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems query string ***id*** was not defined appropriately.

```
<form action="addtoclass.php?id=$id" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code in while loop to:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"addtoclass.php?id=".$res['class_id']."\">Add students</a> | <a href=\"viewstudentsfromclass.php?id=".$res['class_id']."\">View current students</a></td>";
```